# ActionSheet showFromTabBar

Tags: objective-c

Why the animation goes from top to bottom ?

I'd like to show the animation from bottom (TabBar).

```
[ActionButton showFromTabBar:(UITabBar *)self.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[ActionButton showInView:self.view];
```

Comment: I'd just tried it but i received that error in Xcode Presenting action sheet clipped by its superview. Some controls might not respond to touches. On iPhone try -[UIActionSheet showFromTabBar:] or -[UIActionSheet showFromToolbar:] instead of -[UIActionSheet showInView:]. Tried both with not success.